# Is it possible to read a memory value in real time?

Tags: c#, memory

I'm looking to have my program read a value from a memory address, and do some work based on the value of the address. The way I have it done currently is that I have the method executed in a timer every 50 milliseconds, where it reads the address and does the work with the value. Is there any way I could possibly hook onto the address and not need the timer, or atleast read the address whenever it gets updated?

Comment: Is it a property, or is it just pure memory? (Perhaps written to in native code). If there is a setter you can just call an event in the setter.

Comment: It's just pure memory. It's a value from the plugin-container Firefox uses for it's plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old pulling/pushing problem (Interrupts made based on the same concept). You need OS level API hooking when Firefox writes to it's virtual memory. The technique is used for game cheating. `NtWriteVirtualMemory` is a good choice for hooking since you don't need a global hook (just watch Firefox). Usually global hooks to memory writing are used to detect DLL injection (a weak defense against memory patching). [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/system/hooksys.aspx) you can find a god article about API hooking.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how data is being written to the memory address.  If this is data your program writes - you could easily wrap the access to that memory with a method or property (which is a good idea anyways), and raise an event when it changes.

Instead of polling the value, you could then just subscribe to the event.

Comment: What if it's memory that my program doesn't write?

Answer (score 1):

Of course there is, you can use the observer pattern [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).
The observer will execute some work as soon as the value change.

Comment: In C#, events are basically just a language integrated version of the observer pattern.  I would recommend using the built-in language features instead of rolling your own classicly designed "observer".

Comment: ok, i'm not so famillirar with c#, but depending on the aim of this whole application, it could be fun to implment it by hand if it's just a toy project.

Answer (score 0):

The OS may have debugger hooks where you can immediately trap on any write to the virtual memory page where the variable of interest resides.